# ImageMagic gives ' delegate failed `'ufraw-batch' '

Tags: imagemagick, node-imagemagick

```
{ Error: Command failed: identify: delegate failed `'ufraw-batch' --silent --create-id=also --out-type=png --out-depth=16 '--output=%u.png' '%i'' @ error/delegate.c/InvokeDelegate/1919.
identify: unable to open image `/tmp/magick-53080Z_JGYvtuPOl8.ppm': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2841.
```

I got an issue while working with ImageMagick in my node application I did the search but can't get the proper solution for my problem.

Comment: Are the [ufraw](http://ufraw.sourceforge.net/Guide.html) utilities installed on the system?

Comment: yes i have installed it recently still can't find any solution.

Comment: It needs to be installed and ImageMagick recompiled so that it can find it. Does it show up in the list of Delegates as `raw` when you do `convert -version`?

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**: `ufraw` is no longer maintained, so use at your own risk and see `dcraw` alternative lower down.

You need to install 'ufraw-batch'

```
sudo apt-get install ufraw-batch
```

If this does not work, as it did for me. I got a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
This seems to be common problem with ufraw: https://sourceforge.net/p/ufraw/bugs/
It does not seem to get update much anymore, at least not in the main repos.

Converting RAW image into other types of image you can use DCRaw (it is also used by UFRaw).
Here is an example to convert a .cr2 image to a .png:

```
dcraw -c -w "./IMG_1.CR2" | pnmtopng > "./IMG_1.png";
```

Comment: how to convert it to jpg?

Comment: There is also `pnmtojpeg` command if you want them as jpg files. (there are also others if you want to) you can also use the `convert` command to change filetype.

Comment: Thanks this actually worked for me on OS Catalina with ImageMagic 7.0.10. For mac use `brew install ufraw`.

Comment: Ubuntu users: UFRAW is apparently no longer maintained https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFRaw so it shouldn't be installed, and it's also not available on Ubuntu 20 and up unfortunately.

Comment: Added a note to the answer for the unmaintained tool.

Comment: The `dcraw` command didn't work for me when attempting to convert DNG files to JPG (I replaced `pnmtopng` with `pnmtojpeg`). It seemed to mess up the colorspace (?) and caused images to come out in black-and-white.

Comment: `dcraw` has some color options. Maybe you are using a special color-space it does not support? Colors are usually differently encoded in raw formats to allow more flexibility with color-grading afterwords. https://www.dechifro.org/dcraw/dcraw.1.html#lbAG

Answer (score 1):

Macos:

```
brew install ufraw
```

Solved it for me

Comment: ufraw is now disabled from brew...