# Read a tiff image in lua löve (love2d)

Tags: image, lua, tiff, love2d

I wrote a little program using lua [LÖVE](https://love2d.org/). Now I would like to make it read some TIFF files, since LÖVE does not support this image format. And I failed.

Basically, LÖVE can read the file from some userdata. I thought that I might read the data with another library and convert it internally to a format that LÖVE supports, but can't find anything suitable. I looked at [graphicsmagick](https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick) lua bindings, but unfortunately it does not appear to be up to date. I tried to get it too run, but gave up after a while; I would probably have to rewrite the whole package and I can't even find some of the modules it uses (for example the "sys" module).

EDIT: Some more background. I need a fast image viewer to quickly browse through files on the disk. I do not like to use the file manager for that purpose, and I would like it to behave exactly as I want it to behave. I was using `xzgv` for this purpose for years.

When I discovered lua and LÖVE, I decided to write one both as an exercise and because I want to have a little tool like that (you can see how it looks like [here](https://github.com/january3/iv/)).

Comment: If you have ffmpeg than you can do from LÖVE: ```os.execute('ffmpeg -i CYI1f.tiff CYI1f.png')``` - But this works only if the game is not zipped.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing but you can easily convert TIFF images to PNG, or GIF, or NetPBM with **ImageMagick** in your Terminal with `magick INPUT.TIF OUTPUT.PNG` for example.

Comment: Sure, I could convert the files on the command line and read the converted file. What I am doing, however, is a fast image viewer (for my own purposes) and reading + writing + reading the file again is much slower than reading and then converting in memory to a format that LÖVE understands.

Comment: Ok, I see. Cool - and good luck.

Comment: Hah, but you were right, actually! I can simply read the file with Imagemagick but instead of saving the file redirect it to stdout and read the data directly! Thank you!

Comment: Cool. Just FYI, you can force a given filetype on `stdout` with **ImageMagick** like this `magick INPUT.TIF JPEG:-` for JPEG output, or `magick INPUT.TIF PNG32:-` for RGBA8888 PNG output or `magick INPUT.TIF PNG8:-` for palette (indexed) PNG output. And plenty more...

Comment: Yeah, I know, been using Imagemagick many years already ;-) I already implemented it and it works. The only problem I have now is that RAW files don't work: the imagemagick compiled for Ubuntu tries to use `ufraw-batch` and `ufraw` is no longer distributed with Ubuntu. But that is another problem entirely... Also, feel free to formulate the above as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/57712079/2836621

Comment: Sorry, I can't make an answer - that's why I just commented. I know very little about Lua and have no idea how to *"shell out"* to **ImageMagick** with some type of `system()` call and even less idea about how to capture the output of the spawned process, so I'll have to leave it up to you to enlighten me and others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which does not requires any libraries. Basically, the idea is that you convert an image using the `convert` program from the ImageMagick suite and pipe its output to a filehandle with `io.popen`. That way the file is read only once from the storage.

```
local cmd = "/usr/bin/convert %s -format JPG:-"
local file = "test.tiff"

local fh = io.popen(cmd:format(file), "r")
local fdata = fh:read("*a") -- read all
fh:close()

fdata = love.filesystem.newFileData(fdata, file)
local img = love.graphics.newImage(fdata)
```

Comment: Cool - good to see how you do this stuff in Lua. Thanks for sharing.